# jQuery not generating correct queryString

Tags: php, jquery

I have been working on a website that uses a combination of PHP, jQuery, MySQL and XHTML in order to register students for a piano recital. This has no official purpose other than a learning exercise for me in getting all of these to work together. However, I have had a lot of problems getting the PHP to talk with the database and I'm not sure what my problem is. But before that can be tackled there is a really annoying issue that I've run across. For some reason my jQuery is not building a complete post URL for the PHP.

I am using jQuery version: 1.4.2 from Google. The query string is being built by using:

```
var ajaxOpts = {
      type: "post",
      url: "../php/addRecital.php",
      data: "&performance=" + $("#performanceType :selected").text() +
            "&groupName=" + $("#groupName").val() +
            "&student1fName=" + $("#firstName").val() +
            "&student1lname=" + $("#lastName").val() +
            "&student1id=" + $("#studentID").val() +
            "&student2fname=" + $("#Second_Student_firstName").val() +
            "&student2lname=" + $("#Second_Student_lastName").val() +
            "&student2id=" + $("#Second_Student_studentID").val() +
            "&skillSelect=" + $("#skillSelect :selected").text() +
            "&instrument1=" + $("#instument1 :selected").text() +
            "&otherInstrument1=" + $("#otherInstrument1").val() +
            "&instrument2=" + $("#Instument2 :selected").text() +
            "&otherInstrument2=" + $("#otherInstrument2").val() +
            "&location=" + $("#locationSelect :selected").text() +
            "&roomNumber=" + $("#roomNumber").val() +
            "&time=" + $("#timeSlotSelect :selected").text()
            ,
      success: function(data) { ...
```

There is more than the above function, but I didn't think that it would pertain to here. I then call the code using:

```
$.ajax(ajaxOpts);
```

However, instead of creating the entire query string I get:

```
http://sterrcs123.mezoka.com/schoolProject/assign/assign13.html?groupName=&firstName=Samuel&lastName=Terrazas&studentID=23-343-3434&Second_Student_firstName=&Second_Student_lastName=&Second_Student_studentID=&otherInstrument=&Second_Student_Instrument=&roomNumber=2
```

Which as you can tell is missing a number of keys and their values. I would appreciate any help I can get because this is really driving me insane. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read up documentation for the data option. Data is an array of key/value pairs, not a string. Just give it the key and the value and jQuery will take care of adding it to the URL.

Comment: @Sergei: no, data can be a string.

Comment: @Sergai so like: "{ rating: $(this).html() }"? If so then how do I combine multiple key/value pairs?

Comment: Assuming all those are form elements, may want to look in to $('#form').serialize() for the data value.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your form is simply submitting itself without using your AJAX operation.  Did you attach to the form's submit event and THEN run your ajax call?  You will also want to return false from the submit event handler to prevent the default behavior you are seeing above.

Example:

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
       //your ajax code here.
       return false;
});
```

Comment: My "submit" button is just called <button id="add">Register Student</button>, and then im using $("#add").click(function() {}); that is the strange thing.

Comment: I would use the function I have above, and then change your submit button to <input type="submit" value="Register Student" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" />

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking to an ASP.Net web service then you would need data to be a JSON string of your arguments.  Otherwise, you can pass your data in by using an object literal (truncated for brevity):

```
var ajaxOpts = {
  type: "post",
  url: "../php/addRecital.php",
  data: { 
    performance: $("#performanceType :selected").text(),
    groupName: $("#groupName").val(),
    student1fName: $("#firstName").val(),
    student1lname: $("#lastName").val()
  },
  success: function(data) 
}
```

As per the missing values, make sure you're capturing the button click / form submit.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
  $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
  return false;
});
```